# Level-triggered flip-flops in shift register

Tags: digital-logic

I am studying shift registers. My book mentions that level-triggered flip-flops cannot be used to make a serial-in serial-out shift register. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Actually, they can, but it requires a two-phase, non-overlapping clock system.

Comment: @DaveTweed: It requires *at least* two non-overlapping clock phases; the historical designs I'm aware of always used two phases, but storage efficiency could be improved with more.  For example, if a device used four phases, each group of four latches could hold three bits of data (rather than having each pair of latches hold one bit).  A little extra control circuitry would be required, but it's necessary to hold many bits, a a 33% reduction in the number of latches required should be worth something.  Not sure why I've never heard of anyone doing such a thing, though.

Comment: @supercat: I think I see what you're getting at, but it would be slower than the two-phase case. It is the length of the individual phases that determines the timing for any given technology. If you ad more phases per clock cycle, the the clock cycle must necessarily become longer. Besides, the two-phase solution is no worse than the master-slave relationship in the edge-triggered case.

Comment: @DaveTweed: A sequence of e.g. 20 latches operated off four clock phases will hold 15 bits, and clock out one bit every four clock phases.  If one wants to have a device which holds 60 bits and clocks out one bit per clock phase, use four such sequences, each with its clock phases advanced by one relative to the previous; on every clock phase, one sequences will sample its input and one sequence will produce a new output.  Holding 60 bits will thus require about 80 latches, a divide-by-four counter/clock generator, and four pass gates, rather than requiring 120 latches.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Even for a 64-bit shift register, using a 4-phase clock would seem like a "win"; something like the Apple I use 1024-bit shift-register chips, where I would think it would have been an even bigger win, but so far as I know those chips used two-phase clocking throughout.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Each pair of latches can only hold one bit of data during the time when the second latch in the pair is clocked (since the second will match the first).  Thus, holding 60 bits total would require 120 latches.  If one had a string of four latches on different clock phases, then whenever one latch was clocked it would hold the same value as the previous, but the other latches could hold independent values.  Since each foursome would hold 3 bits, one would only need 20 foursomes (80 latches).  It may be possible to use two strings of 40 rather than four of 20, but...

Comment: ...I think having each falling edge of the input clock make the current clock phase go inactive and having the next rising edge make the next clock phase go active, would be easier than trying to have each input clock edge make one clock phase go inactive and make the next one go active, all while assuring ample separation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use level-triggered flip-flops (without a two-phase, non-overlapping clock) then all of the flip-flops will be transparent at the same time. The input to the first flip-flop will propagate all of the way to the output of the last flip-flop whenever the clock input is asserted.

By the way, I think it is better to call a level-sensitive storage element a "latch".

Comment: do you mind explaining it a bit more or guiding me to some online resource

Comment: When the clock is asserted on a level-sensitive flip-flop, the Q output follows the D input...changes on D cause Q to change almost immediately. So, when the clock is asserted the flip-flop behaves pretty much like a simple non-inverting buffer. If it takes \$t_{pd}\$ time for a change in D to propagate to the Q output, and the clock is asserted for \$t_{ckhi}\$, then any change in the D input of the first flip-flop will propagate through \$t_{ckhi}/t_{pd}\$ flip-flops while the clock is asserted. You want the change to propagate through just 1 flip-flop on each clock.